# Can equivalent mass be more than the molecular mass? Can it be applied to radical reactions?

Tags: stoichiometry, radicals

Consider a reaction involving radicals:

$$\ce{CH3^. + Cl^. -> CH3Cl}$$

Is the definition of equivalent mass applicable here? If yes, how?

Are there reactions where equivalent mass of a reagent is more than its molecular mass?

Comment: I think this [Chem-guide](http://chem-guide.blogspot.com/2010/03/equivalent-weight-of-elements-and.html) gets at what you are asking about in the section about compounds, though I must admit I'm almost entirely unfamiliar with the concept of equivalent mass.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_weight  radicals aren't included in the Wikipedia definition